# Micromax A116 ask for 5,13 and 15 digit wi-fi passsword

Tags: wi-fi, connection-issues, password

I recently buy Micromax A116(canvas HD) Running on Android 4.1.2(Jelly-bean), I have problem in wi-fi that when I want to connect my compony wi-fi which is secured with WEP and having password 11 digit but when I'm going to enter password the "connect" button is not enable, It Enable only at digit 5, 13 and 15 but my compony wi-fi of 11 digit. Suggest me the solution for enable "connect" button for all digit password.

Comment: +1 I have the same issue. Couldn't able to connect if small password is kept.